# How to check if input is char or not

Tags: c, input, char

I am learning c and are making a "guess the number" game.
I am getting the player to enter a name and i want to check if it's characters only.

I want to makes this very simple game a little more interesting and add a little more flair to it (i am planning to do coloured text and more.),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    // Initialize array for storing the playes name, players guess, counter for attempts to guess, a bool for the loop //
    // and  lowest and highest number for the random number generator. //
    char player_name[10];
    int player_guess;
    int count_tries = 0;
    
    bool run_game = false;
    
    int lower = 1, higher = 10;

    // Generate a ranom number //
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rand_num = rand() % (lower -higher) + 1;

    // Welcome message //
    printf("WELCOME TO THE GUESSING GAME\n");
    printf("Try to guess the secret number between 1 and 10\n\n");
    // printf("Rand number: %d\n\n", rand_num);
    
    // Get players name //
    printf("What is you name: ", player_name);
    scanf("%s", &player_name);
    }

    // Game Loop //
    do {
        printf("%s what you guess: (between 1 and 10)", player_name);
        scanf("%d", &player_guess);
        if (player_guess < rand_num) {
            printf("%s your guess waa too low!\n", player_name);
            count_tries++;
        }  
        if (player_guess > rand_num) {
            printf("%s your guess was too high!\n", player_name);
            count_tries++;
        }
        if (player_guess == rand_num) {
            printf("Congratulations %s you guessed the correct number!!!\n", player_name);
            count_tries++;
            printf("You guessed the correct number in %d attempts.\n", count_tries);
            break;
        }

    } while(run_game = true);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to do the following, but that does not work either.

```
 if (player_name != char) {
        printf("Names can only be characters");
```

Comment: After you read in the player's name, you need to loop through the string checking each entry for undesirable characters. All entries in a string are characters, you need to be more specific about WHAT KIND of characters you want to check for. Alphabetical? Numerical? Whitespace? etc. Also, when asking the user for a guess, you should be checking the return value of `scanf()` to make sure the user actually entered a valid integer before using the entered value

Comment: Trying to compare the contents of a string using `==` and `!=` isn't going to work. Use `strcmp` or other functions.

Comment: By 'char' and 'character' do you mean *letter*? A `char` is just an integer type with (usually) an 8-bit value. Comparing a value with a type (`char`) isn't valid C code. Also FWIW this `'A'` isn't a `char` but an `int`.

Comment: Every character is a character. Also read [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: PSA: `run_game = true` and `run_game == true` are two *very* different things.

Comment: @Lacochina "(between 1 and 10)"" --> Note `rand() % (lower -higher) + 1` will not generate 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to determine if a string is only alphabetic characters, you need a function that loops over that string, short-circuiting and returning false as soon as it detects a non-alphabetic character.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool only_alpha(const char *s) {
    for (; *s; s++) 
        if (!isalpha((unsigned char)*s))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

If you want this to be a little bit more flexible you can pass a function pointer representing the test to run on each character.

```
bool string_only_contains(const char *s, int (*f)(int)) {
    for (; *s; s++) 
        if (!f((unsigned char)*s))
            return false;

    return true;
}

bool only_alpha(const char *s) {
    return string_only_contains(s, isalpha);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't expecting C to allow taking the address of library functions in the C23 standard with all the `_Generic`s, but _"it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro. This means that an implementation is required to provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a macro for that function"_.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, it works fine now. Edit: How do i close thread?.